# How to submit between php files in the same subdirectory?

Tags: php, html, post

I am working on a project at LocalHost. I show the user some data at first. This happens in the display.php file. Then, I perform some operations with the update button.
The files are in the same directory. Also, there is no error in the definition of action.
There are hundreds of resources on the internet. However, I couldn't find any resource that is processed in the subfolder among them. I would be very grateful if you could guide me on this. However, as a result of the POST operation, I get an error:

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

```
//Main file
//project/index.php
//...


//Display php file
//project/a/display.php
class X {
//...
    public function f_display(){ ?>
    <!--//... -->
    <form action="render.php" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="update-submit">Update</button>
    </form>
    <?php 
    }
}


//php file to be processed
//project/a/render.php

//check if form was submitted
if(isset($_POST['update-submit'])){ 
    echo 'I am here';
}
```

Comment: render.php is on the same directory?

Comment: Yes, it is there.

Comment: What page your web browser is fetching? See on requests on browser.